# Economics perspective of connected workers

Tags: reference-request, labor-economics, theory

According to the Deloitte report published [here](https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/tr/Documents/human-capital/deloitte-the-connected-worker.pdf), a connected worker is defined as someone whose working life is changing due to digital and other technologies. This is due to advancement of technologies, such as, smart wearables, IoTs, Industry 4.0 etc, therefore, enabling the worker to work from anywhere and anytime. This implies that due to these technologies, the geographical and temporal boundaries are becoming less relevant.

Is there any perspectives that we can use from the Economics literature to understand the concept of connected workers?

Comment: *a connected worker is defined as someone whose working life is changing due to digital and other technologies* -- so, just about everybody?

Comment: @1muflon1 here is the report https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/tr/Documents/human-capital/deloitte-the-connected-worker.pdf

Comment: @1muflon1 okay I have done this now.

Comment: However,  human beings are embodied creatures who do live in physical space. So the physical cannot be ignored (and nor should it).

Comment: Can you point out where in the report it says the physical is 'becoming less relevant'? I've quickly glanced through the report and there is no such claim.

Comment: And nor does it say that 'workers can work from anyplace, anywhere'. It does say that some companies might want to look at the changing face of office work -  which is hardly all work -  and that spaces for collaboration and sociality will become more valuable...

Comment: @MoziburUllah it does not say it in the Deloitte report. I have edited the question. But one of the implications of ubiquitous technologies, such as, cloud computing that the report alludes to is that workers are now able to work from anywhere, hence, remote working, and also at any time. Over the years, we have seen a rise in 'gig-economy', platform-economy etc. which further stresses the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look up the 2015 **Journal of Economic Perspective** paper *"Why Are There Still So Many Jobs? The History and Future of Workplace Automation"* by David Autor. Look up the references therein.

Comment: -1: This isn't an answer.

Comment: @MoziburUllah. This is a bit harsh. The paper is written by a well-known economist at MIT and utilises the concept of complementarity, which, in turn, can be used to understand the concept of connected workers.